# Active Directory tree domain not seen from forest DC

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

I have four Hyper-V virtual machines with Windows Server 2012 R2 and Active Directory set up. They are all in an Internal switch configuration and can communicate with each-other fine.

- AD1 is the first DC created in the forest of "domain.com"
- AD2 is the second DC created in the forest of "domain.com"
- AD3 is a child adding the subdomain of "test" to "domain.com"
- AD4 is a tree "tree.com" added to the forest "domain.com"

In AD1 there is no entry for the "domain" of AD4, while in AD4 you can see it fine.

I was wondering why that could be and how to fix it.

[image: View from AD1]
[image: View from AD2]